# can i decorate a `__getattr__` method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Is it possible to decorate methods like `__getattr__` in python?

Like this

```
@myWrapper
def __getattr__(self,attrName):
    '''
    myCode Goes here
    '''
```

when i tried to use something like above i got some error:

Thanks to willem for pointing out..

i identified the error i had made in the code.

my intention was to do something like this

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=someObject()
    @mywrapper
    def __getattr__(self,argName):
        # call self.a 's  method. If that doesnt have
        # then raise an exception
```

so my method may have some arguments and i need to pass that too..

so i wrote something like this to test:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=someObject()
    @mywrapper
    def __getattr__(self,argName):
        print('getAttr called for {}'.format(argName))
        def mymethod(*args,**kwargs):
            import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        return mymethod
```

my wrapper code looks like below:

```
def mywrapper(method):
    def methodWrapper(obj,name):
        print("In decorator for {}".format(method));
        method(obj,name)
    return methodWrapper
```

but when i execute like obj.c(1) i get the below exception

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Infact the print statements in both the decorator and the `__getattr__` are getting executed but i am seeing the exception..

How to resolve this?

Comment: pls, paste also code of your decorator

Comment: Sure. What exactly is `myWrapper` doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. `__getattr__` is in fact *just another function*, although the Python interpreter will call it as one of its *fallback mechanisms*. There is nothing *inherently* special about `__init__`, `__getattr__`, etc.

By convention however names with leading and tailing double underscores however are *"magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as documented."*. But that is a *style guideline* (that you better follow).

For some reason however, your `@myWrapper` **does not respect the (number of) attributes**.

If you for instance would write a wrapper:

```
def myWrapper(func):
    def g(self,attrName):
        return func(self,'foo_%s'%attrName)
    return g
```

Then there is *no* problem.

If we now define a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo:

    @myWrapper
    def __getattr__(self,attrName):
        print(attrName)
```

Then we see, that the decorator works correctly:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bla
foo_bla
```

as you can see, the `__getattr__` prints `foo_bla` so that means that `myWrapper` has prepended the attribute with `foo_`.

As for your (edited) question, I guess the reason why it says "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" is because **a decorator should *return* a (new) function**.

Probably your decorator looks something like:

```
def mywrapper(func):
    def g(self,attrName):
        return func(self,attrName)
```

So you probably forgot to call `return g`.

**EDIT**: based on your updated question, the problem is that you do *not* return the result of the inner `__getattr__` call:

```
def mywrapper(method):
    def methodWrapper(obj,name):
        print("In decorator for {}".format(method));
        return method(obj,name) -- with a return statement
    return methodWrapper
```

This is important since you `__getattr__` *returns a function*. Note that in the context of `mywrapper`, the `method` is the *original* `__getattr__` and the `methodWrapper` is the new `__getattr__`. So you should pass the result of the original `__getattr__`. Right now you don't do anything with it and return (by default) `None`.

Comment: My wrapper does that:

my wrapper code looks like

    def mywrapper(method):
        def methodWrapper(obj,name):
             print("In decorator");method(obj,name)
        return methodWrapper

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran: there is *no* return in your inner `method(obj,name)` call. So that means that what your `__getattr__` is returning, will *never* be returned.

Comment: I am sorry.. i am not able to get it still..

myWrapper is my decorator which returns methodWrapper func object.

and my __getattr__ is decorated with myWrapper..

and i have a defined one more function mymethod inside __getattr__ where i have a breakpoint also and i am returning this mymethod function pointer from __getattr__.. what am i missing! :(

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran: it is a bit confusing. Can you please edit your question write a (minimal complete) version of your wrapper together with an error message. It is not that I want to be annoying, but currently it's a bit vague.

Comment: @WillemVonOsem Thanks for the pointing out the errors.. just one more clarification.. so in this case i cant write a generic wrapper than can be used for both a method that i have defined inside the class [case-1] and methods that i have not defined(that will be handled by __getattr__)[case-2]..

since in [case-1] the 2nd argument in methodWrapper would have to be the arguments to the class method and in [case-2] it will the name of the attribute called by the user..

is there some way i can write a generic wrapper for both the cases?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144348/discussion-between-arun-kaliraja-baskaran-and-willem-van-onsem).